# Error: UNKNOWN errno: -4094, readlink :C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\oyebusy-beauty\oyebusy-web\oyebusy-webapp\.next\server\app-paths-manifest.json

Tags: error-handling, documentation, next.js13, error-code, error-correction

I am facing this error while running "npm run dev" in my next js app . I didn't find documentation of this error code so if anyone can help it'd be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

this is my path's page

```
{
  "/page": "app/page.js",
  "/plumbers/page": "app/plumbers/page.js"
}
```

Comment: Try deleting your **.next** folder and make build again by npm run build and start by npm start

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked by following these steps